# After upgrading to React 16 componentDidUpdate causing an infinite loop when calling redux-form action creator

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a form that I want to run a mathematical calculation across fields when the component loads.

If the user selects 'grid' from a drop-down, the fields render with a calculation based on a set of default values. If a user changes the values of any of the fields, it recalculates on each new value entered.

Before upgrading to React 16, from 15, and from Redux-Form 7+ to 8, this worked by dispatching a redux-form action creator in a componentWillUpdate lifecycle method. Now, it causes an infinite loop.

I've updated from the componentWillUpdate method to the preferred componentDidUpdate method suggested when migrating to React 16.

I've placed a conditional in the method, as the docs suggest when setting state, but the method continues to call itself when I do.

I've tried various other approaches, including onChange handlers, but I need the values to be calculated before the component renders after each key stroke.

```
// here is the conditional for when the user selects grid in a drop-down, and the other to compare a field called gredThetaIncrement when a user inputs a new value. There are several other fields I need to compare as well, but it fails even when testing with one.

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.thetaDistribution === 'grid' && prevProps.gridThetaIncrement !== this.props.gridThetaIncrement) {
      this.calculateThetaPointsAndTestTakers(this.props)
    }
    return null;
  }
```

```
// method to handle the calculations, where using a redux-form action creator is calling setState() and no doubt causing the infinite loop

  calculateThetaPointsAndTestTakers(props) {
    const {
      thetaLowerBound,
      thetaUpperBound,
      gridThetaIncrement,
      gridTestTakersPerTheta,
      thetaDistribution,
    } = props;

    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    const multiplier = Math.max(
      findMultiplier(thetaUpperBound - thetaLowerBound),
      findMultiplier(gridThetaIncrement)
    );
    const totalThetaPoints =
      Math.trunc(
        ((thetaUpperBound - thetaLowerBound) * multiplier) /
        (gridThetaIncrement * multiplier)
      ) + 1;

    const testTakerCount = totalThetaPoints * gridTestTakersPerTheta;

    dispatch(change('simulationForm', 'totalThetaPoints', totalThetaPoints));
    dispatch(change('simulationForm', 'testTakerCount', testTakerCount));
  }
```

The result should be a calculation that updates across redux-form fields after every new value input.

here is a sandbox of the breaking code. https://codesandbox.io/embed/redux-form-template-jhrn7?fontsize=14

select 'grid' in the dropdown and the infinite loop will break the page.

Appreciate any help understanding componentDidUpdate or how to pull this off. I have 4 different fields I need to calculate the values against based on user input. An onChange method for each calling the calculation method on each input seems redundant. I'm sure there's a better way I'm just not realizing.

Answer (score 0):

When `gridThetaIncrement` change, you trigger `calculateThetaPointsAndTestTakers`, which dispatch props (trigger `componentDidUpdate` but does not fulfill the condition), which then trigger `onChange` of your fields, including `thetaDistribution`, which trigger his `onChange` method, which call `handleThetaDistributionChange`, which dispatch `gridThetaIncrement`, which call `componentDidUpdate` and fulfill your condition, which starts the loop again.